# GetComponent isn't working with Unity 5.2

Tags: c#

I'm trying to follow along to this tutorial http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores

But it hasn't been updated to Unity 5.2 and I can't get the GetComponent to work no matter what I try.

```
 IEnumerator GetScores()
 {
 GameObject text = new GameObject ("Loading Scores");
 text.GetComponent<GUIText>();
 WWW hs_get = new WWW(highscoreURL);
 yield return hs_get;

 if (hs_get.error != null)
 {
     print("There was an error getting the high score: " + hs_get.error);
 }
 else
 {
     GetComponent<GUIText>(hs_get.text); //Line of code not working
           // this is a GUIText that will display the scores in game.
 }
}
```

The error is: Assets/HSController.cs(46,25): error CS0308: The non-generic method `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent(System.Type)' cannot be used with the type arguments

I can't seem to get GetComponent working any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
text.text = hs_get.text;
```

I'm not entirely sure what your code is supposed to do, but I don't know why you're using GetComponent. If you don't want to reuse the "text" variable, then you could maybe try something like

```
hsText = GetComponent <GUIText> ();
hsText.text = hs_get.text;
```

I don't know if I'm addressing the problem but I hope this helps!